# Measurability and Open Sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a homework question, as follows: Can there be a Lebesgue measurable set $A$ such that

$$\lambda(A\cap U)=\frac{\lambda(U)}{2}$$
for all open sets $U$?

I’ve made two observations:

1. If such an $A$ exists, it’s measure must be infinity, since $$\lambda(A\cap \mathbb{R})=\lambda(A)=\frac{\lambda(\mathbb{R})}{2}$$
2. If such an $A$ exists, it cannot contain an open subset $U$, since $$\lambda(A\cap U)=\lambda(U)=\frac{\lambda(U)}{2} $$ which implies that an open set has nonpositive measure, a contradiction.

Past these observations I’m stuck, and have no real intuition on whether this thing should exist or not. My gut says no, as it seems too convenient to let us pick among every open set and this nice equality holds, but I can’t seem to pin a contradiction. I was hoping there would be some implication that the measure of $A$ was also finite, which would imply that it couldn’t exist.

Comment: the following might give you some ideas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem Lebesgue's density theorem. (And, I think your second observation is fine, one may assume the open $U$ is bounded.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber You are correct. I see now

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer myself, but I can add another observation - $A$ cannot be closed. Indeed, it must of course nontrivially intersect every nonempty open subset of $\mathbb R$, so it is dense. If it was closed, then $A = \overline A = \mathbb R$ but this obviously does not satisfy the desired property.

Answer (score 2):

By the regularity of the Lebesgue measure, there exists an open set $U\supset A$ such that $\lambda(U\setminus A) < \varepsilon$. Can you see how this, together with your observations thus far about $A$, leads to a contradiction?

Comment: I have a suspicion, so either yes or very much no. Is it that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is this open $U_\varepsilon$ with the property you described, so that as $\varepsilon\to 0$ the $U_\varepsilon \to A$ so $A$ must be open?

Comment: Note that any measurable set may be approximated by an open set from “outside”, though measurable sets can be far from open (in particular, $A$ could be far from open).

But what is true is that for our set $U$ is that all but $\varepsilon$ of its measure lies inside $A$. This almost makes $U$ violate the definition of $A$: If we pretend for a moment that $U$ had measure $1$, we would see that it would have  $1-\varepsilon > 1/2$ measure in $A$. Of course, $U$ has infinite measure, since it contains $A$. But can you tweak $U$ to have finite measure and get a contradiction?

Comment: I can think to write $U$ as a collection of open intervals, but there’s no reason to think those intervals should have finite length or their lengths should be finite. I can cover $U\setminus A$ with intervals and their lengths sum to $\varepsilon$.

Comment: $U\cap (-n,n)$ for sufficiently large $n$ should give you what you need.

Comment: Does this set take the place of $U$, or is this an open set which causes us to violate our condition that $\lambda(A \cap U)= \frac{\lambda(U)}{2}$?

Comment: Note that $\lambda(U\cap (-n, n))\to \lambda(U) = \infty$ as $n\to\infty$. So, for sufficiently large $n$, $U\cap (-n, n)$ (which is an open set) should cause us to violate the condition defining $A$. (And it does take the place of $U$ in the argument I sketched two comments above.)